# Sum in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database with a table "Bill" like this:

```
ID    |    Name    |    Money
1     |    A       |    100
2     |    B       |    150
3     |    C       |    200
```

I want to create a procedure that return me data like this:

```
ID    |    Name    |    Money    |    Tax    |    Total
1     |    A       |    100      |    10     |    110
2     |    B       |    150      |    15     |    165
3     |    C       |    200      |    20     |    220
```

with Tax = (Money*10)/100

and Total = Money + Tax

How can I do this. I'm using sql server 2008

Comment: I really don't know why people post the same unswer :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select id, name, money, (money*.10) as tax, (money*1.10) as Total
from Bill
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f84ca/1)

Result:

```
| ID | NAME | MONEY | TAX | TOTAL |
-----------------------------------
|  1 |    A |   100 |  10 |   110 |
|  2 |    B |   150 |  15 |   165 |
|  3 |    C |   200 |  20 |   220 |
```

Comment: And I have a question: If "Tax" is 10.544, I want it returns 10.54 or "Tax" is 10.546, I want it returns 10.55. How can I do this?

Comment: @furyfish you can use the [`round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) function. See this demo --http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f84ca/4

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id
    ,NAME
    ,MONEY
    ,(MONEY * 10) / 100 AS Tax
    ,MONEY + ((MONEY * 10) / 100) AS Total
FROM Bill
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Name, Money, Money * 0.1 as Tax,  Money * 1.1 as Total FROM Bill
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID,Name,[Money],[Money]*10/100  as Tax,[Money]+ [Money]*10/100 as Total
From Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 SELECT    [Id]
          ,[Name]
          ,[Money]
          ,[Money] * .1 AS [Tax]
          ,[Money] * 1.1 AS [Total]
 FROM [Bill]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select [ID]
,[Name]
,[Money]
,convert(decimal(10,0), (([Money] * 10) / 100)) as [Tax]
,convert(decimal(10,0), [Money] + (([Money] * 10) / 100)) as [Total]
from [Bill]
```

Note that I'm `convert`ing to `decimal(10, 0)` to have a 0 precision just to match your results.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure will return what you need.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Select_Bills] 
AS
BEGIN
      SELECT Id, Name, Money, (mMoney*.10) as Tax, (Money*1.10) as Total
      FROM Bill
END
```